# Iterating on Pandas DataFrame to pass data into API

Tags: python, pandas, api, erp

I am creating a script that reads a GoogleSheet, transforms the data and passes it into my ERP API to automate the creation of Purchase Orders.

I have got as far as outputting the data in a dataframe but I need help on how I can iterate through this and pass it in the correct format to the API.

DataFrame Example (dfRow):

```
   productID  vatrateID  amount  price
0      46771          2       1   1.25
1      46771          2       1   2.25
2      46771          2       2   5.00
```

Formatting of the API data:

```
              vatrateID1=dfRow.vatrateID[0],
              amount1=dfRow.amount[0],
              price1=dfRow.price[0],
              productID1=dfRow.productID[0],
              vatrateID2=dfRow.vatrateID[1],
              amount2=dfRow.amount[1],
              price2=dfRow.price[1],
              productID2=dfRow.productID[1],
              vatrateID3=dfRow.vatrateID[2],
              amount3=dfRow.amount[2],
              price3=dfRow.price[2],
              productID3=dfRow.productID[2],
```

I would like to create a function that would iterate thru the DataFrame and return the data in the correct format to pass to the API.

I'm new at Python and struggle most with iterating / loops so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First, you can always loop over the rows of a dataframe using `df.iterrows()`. Each step through this iterator yields a tuple containing the row index and the row contents as a pandas Series object. So, for example, this would do the trick:

```
for ix, row in df.iterrows():
    for column in row.index:
       print(f"{column}{ix}={row[column]}")
```

You can also do it without resorting to loops. This is great if you need performance, but if performance isn't a concern then it is really just a matter of taste.

```
# first, "melt" the data, which puts all of the variables on their own row
x = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index')

# now join the columns together to produce the rows that we want
s = x['variable'] + x['index'].map(str) + '=' + x['value'].map(str)

print(s)

0     productID0=46771.0
1     productID1=46771.0
2     productID2=46771.0
3         vatrateID0=2.0
...
10           price1=2.25
11            price2=5.0
```

Comment: This is brilliant - thanks!  But now I am having issues passing this into the API call.  I am returning the DF with your code + dfRow = dfRow.values.  When I pass 'dfRow' as a variable in the API call, I get "SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument."  Any ideas on how I can get past this issues?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the details, but googling that error message should get you somewhere.